# Assistance with counting the numbers in a file

Tags: python

I am trying to get the values in alist to be the number of occurences of 0-9 in a file. I am not sure where I messed up because after running the code alist is still all 0's.

```
def main():
    intro()
    inFile = getFile()
    file, outfile = convertName(inFile)
    alist, count = countLines(file, outfile)
    printResults(alist, count, outfile)

def intro():
    print()
    print("Program to count letters in each line")
    print("in a file.")
    print("You will enter the name of a file.")
    print("The program will create an output file.")
    print("Written by .")
    print()
def getFile():
    inFile = input("Enter name of input file:  ")
    return inFile
def convertName(inFile):
    file = open(inFile, "r")
    outfile = (inFile.replace(".txt", ".out"))
    return file, outfile
def countLines(file, outfile):
    outfile = open(outfile, "w")
    alist = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    count = 0
    for line in file:
        count = count + 1
        spl = line.split()       
        for i in range(0,10):
            for ch in spl:
                if ch == i:
                    alist[i] = alist[i+1]
    return alist, count
def printResults(alist, count, outfile):
    print("The name of output file is", outfile)
    print()
    print("Number of lines:          ", count)
    t = 0
    print(alist)
main()
```

Comment: `alist[i] = alist[i+1]` should be `alist[i] = alist[i]+1`

Comment: `aList = [v for k,v in sorted(list(collections.Counter(filter(lambda c:c.isdigit(), itertools.chain.from_iterable(file))).items()), key=lambda (a,b):int(a))]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    for i in range(0,10):
        for ch in spl:
            if ch.isdigit() and int(ch) == i:
                alist[i] += 1
```

Comment: @user3015970, please consider to upvote gnibblers answers if it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

In:

```
alist[i] = alist[i+1]
```

you are assigning the element 0 to `alist[i]`. You may want to do something like:

```
alist[i] += 1
```

Comment: Put a `print` inside the `if ch == i:` and make sure your program is getting into it. If not, the logic program is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want those counts (without counting numbers), use `collections.Counter`

```
from collections import Counter
def count_digits(file_name):
    with open(fn):
        c = Counter([int(character) for character in open(fn).read() if character.isdigit()])
    return [c.get(i,0) for i in range(10)]
```

if you also want the number of lines, extend the method a little:

```
from collections import Counter
def count_digits(file_name):
    with open(fn) as fh:
        c = Counter([int(character) for character in fh.read() if character.isdigit()])
        digit_counts = [c.get(i,0) for i in range(10)]
        fh.seek(0)
        lines_count = sum(1 for line in fh)
    return digit_counts, line_counts
```